# Create Table using SQL with primary key starting with 'A'

Tags: sql, oracle, check-constraints

I'm trying to create a table using SQL. I want my **primary key** **- ArCode** to start with the letter **'A'**. I have used combinations of **check** and **like** but to no avail.

Here is my Query:

```
Create table Article(
ArCode Char(5) Check (ArCode LIKE 'A%') Primary Key,
ArName Varchar2(30) Not Null,
Rate Number(8,2),
Quantity Number(4) Check (Quantity >=0) Default 0,
Class Char(1) Check (Class In ('A','B','C'))
);
```

When I execute the query I get a **missing right parenthesis** error. I'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: MySQL check constraints are only parsed but not enforced.

Comment: If you are using MySQL, you should know that MySQL does not implement `check` constraints, so you have to do this with a trigger.

Comment: Lets say I'm  using Oracle

Comment: then why tag your question mysql?

Comment: I have formatted it.

Comment: Why `char`? `varchar2` is the standard string type, `char` is the weird unhelpful one provided for ANSI compatibility, not for actual use.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question.. I too had the same doubt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is with the definition of the Quantity column.  Commenting that out, or just fixing it such that default comes before the check constraint allows the create table statement to run just fine:

```
Create table Article(
  ArCode Char(5) Check (ArCode LIKE 'A%') Primary Key,
  ArName Varchar2(30) Not Null,
  Rate Number(8,2),
--  Quantity Number(4) Check (Quantity >=0) Default 0,
  Quantity Number(4)  Default 0 Check (Quantity >=0),
  Class Char(1) Check (Class In ('A','B','C'))
);
```

Comment: Ok, I get it. Also, you have to include the primary key before the check constraint. Thanks :)

Comment: No I don't think there is anything wrong with the order of the primary key and check constraints on ArCode.  Least wise the DDL worked fine for me after the above fix in Oracle 18c XE.  The Primary Key and Check statements are both constraints, whereas on Quantity, the Default statement is not a constraint so is parsed separately.

Comment: If I were to learn more about constraints, what would be your suggestion regarding a good resource?

Comment: The Oracle [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52180)